# Grails server landing page

Tags: grails

Is there a way so that I can set up a landing page for my Grails server? I don't want to go to

`www.hostname.com/application` I would like to be able to see `www.hostname.com/application` when I do `www.hostname.com:8080` is this possible? I already have the dns mapping taken care of I just need help to configure my Grails server to respond with a landing page when I request `www.hostname.com/8080`.

Comment: Why not deploy your application as ROOT.war to to your container? That way it responds at the ROOT application e.g: www.hostname.com/

Comment: @Joshua Moore I have never done this before I usually just do grails run-app while I am developing. I did now just make a war file and can run it by using grails run-war but I am not sure how to go about getting it the way you are suggesting though what you are suggesting it exactly what I need. I'd appreciate any pointers. My application is running on an Amazon Web Service Ec2 Amazon Linux instance. Right now Im accessing it using a long ugly url but would ideall like to get to my customer's login page using www.hostname.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build a war file named `ROOT.war`, e.g. by executing `grails war ROOT.war` and copy that to Tomcat's<sup>1</sup> `/webapps` directory, you application will run in the root context, i.e. the homepage will be displayed at `www.hostname.com:8080`

1. I've assumed your app is running on Tomcat, based on nothing more than the balance of probability

### Update

To change the `www.hostname.com:8080` to `www.hostname.com` change the following in the tomcat configuration file `conf/server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

to

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to do just www.hostname.com, without the '8080'?

Comment: you should chain tomcat with apache together, like the whole world is doing this :) then you can leave the port unchanged (or block the entire `HTTP-connector`) and set the propper port in apache config

Comment: @injecteer, sounds like this chaining of tomcat with apache is the thing I need to figure out how to do and then I have lots more options. Thanks.

Comment: @injecteer Two questions in this regard, isn't apache already part of tomcat? I thought an application server always housed a web server inside it. And secondly isn't tomcat already part of the grails server mechanism? If I have grails installed do I still need tomcat by itself?

Comment: 1. no apache doesn't belong to tomcat, apache can be configured to delegate certain requests to tomcat via HTTP or AJP 2. tomcat-plugin is used only for `run-app`. If you package your app as a .war-file, it has no references to tomcat's libraries

Answer (score 1):

you can also set the `application.name = /` in the application.properties to have the same set-up for testing under `localhost`